# Why header file change is ignored in building TCL source?

Tags: tcl

In TCL source tree, unix/Makefile, I notice that header files are not part of dependency of any C source file. For example:

```
tclCmdAH.o: $(GENERIC_DIR)/tclCmdAH.c
        $(CC) -c $(CC_SWITCHES) $(GENERIC_DIR)/tclCmdAH.c
```

This ends up, if I update tcl.h and run make, the change is not picked up at all. I need to totally clean the directory and then run make.

Did I miss anything? Or any reason is it done this way?

Comment: Mmmh. Could you tell us more about the sort of change you are seeking? What is your expectation? Changes to declarations in, e.g., `tclCmdAH.c` must reflected in `tclInt.h`, never in `tcl.h`. Hence, no dependency to `tcl.h`. As you would have to touch both `tclCmdAH.c` and `tclInt.h` to complete a change, this would be picked up by `make` anyways. I fail to see your point, I am afraid.

Comment: `I notice that header files are not part of dependency of any C source file`. This is not the case, watch for the *HDR and *HDRS variables in the Makefile. There is no dependency to `tclInt.h` (with one exception) and `tcl.h`, but they are not needed (see my first comment).

Comment: It's not usually a problem when developing, as doing a `make clean test` isn't many more characters to type than `make test`, and doesn't take hugely longer on modern hardware… but if you're making subtle changes to a header file that affect a specific object then it can be worthwhile making the dependency explicit.